# How can I re-use an existing database connection in phpBB3?

Tags: php, database, connection, phpbb3

I am using my own db for phpbb3 forum, and I wish to insert some data from the forum into my own tables. Now, I can make my own connection and it runs my query but in trying to use the $db variable(which I think is what you're meant to use??) it gives me an error.

I would like someone to show me the bare bones which i insert my query into to be able to run it.

Answer (score 1):

Well.. You haven't given us very much information, but there are two things you need to do to connect and query to a database.

For phpbb, you may want to read the documentation they have presented:

http://wiki.phpbb.com/Database_Abstraction_Layer

Here is a general overview of how you'd execute a query:

```
include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/db/mysql.' . $phpEx);

$db = new dbal_mysql();
// we're using bertie and bertiezilla as our example user credentials. You need to fill in your own ;D
$db->sql_connect('localhost', 'bertie', 'bertiezilla', 'phpbb', '', false, false);

$sql = "INSERT INTO (rest of sql statement)";

$result = $db->sql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

I presumed that phpBB already had a connection to my database. Thus I wasnt going to use a new one? Can i make a new one and call it something else and not get an error?

And $resultid = mysql_query($sql,$db345);

Where $db345 is the name of my database connection

Comment: If php is like any other database I've used then you should be able to have as many connections as the database suports. Which is usually greater than 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
$db = new dbal_mysql();
// we're using bertie and bertiezilla as our example user credentials. You need to fill in your own ;D
$db->sql_connect('localhost', 'bertie', 'bertiezilla', 'phpbb', '', false, false);

$sql = "INSERT INTO (rest of sql statement)";
$result = $db->sql_query($sql);
```